# To grab only jpg file image

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a program to show picture from my folder.

The code:

```
$dir = dir("tags/carrot_cake");
while($filename=$dir->read()) {

    if($filename == "." || $filename == ".." || $filename == $first_image) continue;

    echo "<div class='cp-thumb'>";

    /**********************************sql query to fetch date time and caption************************/
     $timeqry = mysql_query("SELECT created_date FROM foodsites.images WHERE img_name='$filename'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($timeqry);
     $datetime = $row1[0];
     $newDatetime = date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($datetime));
     $capqry =  mysql_query("SELECT caption FROM foodsites.images WHERE img_name='$filename'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($capqry);
     $caption = $row2[0];

     echo "<div class='cp-hover' style='display: none;' ><div class='cpHover-bg'></div>
            <div class='cpHover-info'><p class='text11'>".$newDatetime."</p><p class='text10'>".$caption."</p></div></div>"; 
     echo "<img src='tags/carrot_cake/".$filename."'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";  
}
```

In my code, I found out I fetch all the file inside the directory includes those which are not jpg file.

How do I change it to only grab jpg file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
if($filename == "." || $filename == ".." || $filename == $first_image) continue;
```

to:

```
if ($filename != "." && $filename != ".." && strtolower(substr($filename , strrpos($filename , '.') + 1)) == 'jpg') continue;
```

Another way to do that is with  [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob):

```
$filename = glob('/tags/carrot_cake/*.jpg');
```

In the `glob()` case this returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
while($filename=$dir->read()) {
        $allowed='jpg';  //which file types are allowed seperated by comma

        $extension_allowed=  explode(',', $allowed);
        $file_extension=  pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(array_search($file_extension, $extension_allowed))
        {
           //allowed
        }
        else
        {
            //not allowed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Extension is not always a good way to check if image is JPEG or not

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir = dir("tags/carrot_cake");
while($filename=$dir->read()) {

    $filename_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($filename));

    if($filename == "." || $filename == ".." || $filename == $first_image || ($filename_mime != "image/pjpeg" || $filename_mime != "image/jpeg")) continue;

    echo "<div class='cp-thumb'>";

    /**********************************sql query to fetch date time and caption************************/
     $timeqry = mysql_query("SELECT created_date FROM foodsites.images WHERE img_name='$filename'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($timeqry);
     $datetime = $row1[0];
     $newDatetime = date('d/m/Y h:i A', strtotime($datetime));
     $capqry =  mysql_query("SELECT caption FROM foodsites.images WHERE img_name='$filename'") or die(mysql_error());
     $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($capqry);
     $caption = $row2[0];

     echo "<div class='cp-hover' style='display: none;' ><div class='cpHover-bg'></div>
            <div class='cpHover-info'><p class='text11'>".$newDatetime."</p><p class='text10'>".$caption."</p></div></div>"; 
     echo "<img src='tags/carrot_cake/".$filename."'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";  
}
?>
```

Comment: In this example I am using MIME type of each file to see if there is a JPEG image. Extension is not always a guaranteed way to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: This answer is not for this question, I think. He asked how to detect JPEG files and show only them.